# how to make testText to text text in typescript

Tags: typescript

this is my first question so if I make mistakes I'm really sorry

I have a variable called foo and it contains the string "helloWorld"
is there any way to make it to "hello world" like how unity does with the variables in the script

Im using typescript btw

and Thanks

Comment: With just the one example, i have to guess a bit what you're after. Is this accurate: you want to be able to take in any camelCase string and turn it into a space-separated string? eg, "fooBar" to "foo bar" or "fooBarBaz" to "foo bar baz"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex replace should do the trick for you:

```js
"fooBarBaz".replace(/[A-Z]/g, (m) => " " + m.toLowerCase());
// "foo bar baz"
```